# For Swift, is Double? the same as Optional<Double>?

Tags: swift, option-type

```
    var title: Double? = nil
    var title2 = Optional<Double>.None
```

The two things above seem to both behave as optional Doubles. But when I hold option and click on `title` and `title2`, it shows that they have different types. One is `Double?` and the other is `Optional<Double>`. I'm just wondering if theres a difference between the two. And if they aren't different, why even have two of them? Was Optional an objective C thing that got transferred over to swift or something?

Comment: There  is no difference. `T?` is a shortcut for `Optional<T>`.

Comment: Try `print(title.dynamicType)` and `print(title2.dynamicType)`.

Comment: There are no "optionals" in Objective-C, so it is definitely not a remnant from there :)

Comment: @MartinR arguably, there are only optionals in Objective-C :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, and there is nothing special about `Double` here.

For *any* type `T`, `T?` is a (compiler built-in)
shortcut for `Optional<T>`. So

```
var value: T?
var value: Optional<T>
```

are equivalent. `Optional` conforms to the `NilLiteralConvertible`
protocol, i.e. a value can be instantiated from the literal `nil`, and

```
var value: T? = nil
var value: T? = .None
var value: T? = Optional.None
var value: T? = Optional<T>.None
var value: T? = T?.None
```

are all equivalent. In the first three statements, the type
`Optional<T>` of the value on the right-hand side is inferred from the type annotation on the left-hand
side. The last two statements can be shortened to

```
var value = Optional<T>.None
var value = T?.None
```

because the type is inferred automatically from the right-hand side.

Finally, since optionals are implicitly initialized to `.None`,
*all* of the above statements are equivalent.